# Use WSO2 ESB Connector to send ISO8583 message to server

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

I have implemented all the mentioned instruction in the official wso2 inbound and connector documentation, when I send the message to the JavaTest server the proxy service that I used to send XML Message through stop working and nothing appear in the log, Alos the server does not receive the ISO message unless I restart the ESB, the message shown up in the server once I restart it!

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see the above log in your ESB console, then you have to put the following in your configuration.

```
<log level="full"/>
```

The reason for server doesn't receive the message, may be your server doesn't handle the socket connections properly. Try it with this one https://github.com/Kanapriya/ISO8583TestServer